# Mechanism for Lucas Test

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

In the mechanism for Lucas' Test for Alcohols, I am reading two different types. One says the first step is the abstraction of a proton from HCl, but on other references, I also see that the first step is the formation of a zinc chloride complex. Anyone can clear this out for me? Thanks

Comment: The first step is the formation of the complex $\ce{ZnCl4^{2-}}$. Then the alcohol reacts with this complex and makes a new intermediate complex having two new bonds, one Zn-OH, and one Zn-R. Later on, Zn would go back to a tetra-coordinate complex, by keeping the OH group, then loosing R and one Cl atom, which produces R-Cl.

Comment: See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89945/what-is-the-function-of-zncl2-in-lucas-test) and the question linked in the comments.